# Could not install packages due to Environment Error | pipenv

Tags: python, terminal, pip, pipenv

Trying to install pipenv. Getting long error messages.

Tried:

```
sudo -H pip install pipenv
sudo pip install pipenv 
pip install pipenv
```

The error message that shows up:

```
ERROR: Could not install packages due to an EnvironmentError: [('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/markers.pyc', '/private/tmp/pip-uninstall-NRtYTX/markers.pyc', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/private/tmp/pip-uninstall-NRtYTX/markers.pyc'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/__init__.py', '/private/tmp/pip-uninstall-NRtYTX/__init__.py', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/private/tmp/pip-uninstall-NRtYTX/__init__.py'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/markers.py', '/private/tmp/pip-uninstall-NRtYTX/markers.py', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/private/tmp/pip-uninstall-NRtYTX/markers.py'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib/__init__.pyc', '/private/tmp/pip-uninstall-NRtYTX/__init__.pyc', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/private/tmp/pip-uninstall-NRtYTX/__init__.pyc'"), ('/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/_markerlib', '/private/tmp/pip-uninstall-NRtYTX', "[Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/private/tmp/pip-uninstall-NRtYTX'")]
```

Comment: did you checked of directory /private/tmp/ ?

Comment: `pip install --user pipenv`